Cannot reference BigQuery temp table after creation
I am receiving the following error when trying to pull data from a temp table I just created in the statement immediately before.
Invalid value: Table "tt_orders" must be qualified with a dataset (e.g. dataset.table). at [..get_order_report:121:17]
When I add the dataset qualifier, I get this message.
Not found: Table :.tt_orders was not found in location US at [..get_order_report:121:17]
The flow of the stored procedure is this:
Set some variables
--> Create temp table tt_orders as ()
--> Use tt_orders to create another temp table tt_DN which is a list of names.
I use tt_orders to limit the dataset and only pull the relevent names associated with orders
--> about 4 more temp tables are creating pulling various data needed for the report
--> join data together and return report results to client
this is the psuedo code for the failing query. Also ight be important is this is ported from an existing SQL Server stored procedure
    CREATE TEMP TABLE tt_Names AS (
    SELECT tmp.OrderID AS OrderId
        ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY d.OrderId ORDER BY dc.DateCreated) AS RowNum 
        ,dc.Name 
    FROM tt_orders tmp
        INNER JOIN `<dataset>.Table1` d ON tmp.OrderId=d.OrderId
    INNER JOIN `<dataset>.Table2` dc ON dc.SecondaryID = d.SecondaryID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ID FROM UNNEST(FilteredIds) AS ID) tc ON d.SecondaryId=tc.ID 
    WHERE tc.ID IS NOT NULL);

Is there a special way to call a temp table within a stored procedure?
Thanks in advance
I have run the code both with and without the dataset qualified and both ways give me errors.

seems to me like your error is in the definition of the temp table itself. The temp table you are trying to create it "tt_Names" but your error is regarding the FROM tt_orders, which makes no sense as far as I can see, unless you are omitting part of your script.

I'm omitting just the statements before. Prior statement is "create temp table tt_order as" statement pulling from permanent tables to get a list of orders valid for the query based on a dozen filters or so. That all ran as expected. Its just when I try to access the temp table I just created that I am getting the error. Its very odd to me.
